# PHP text to image, text alignment

Tags: php, alignment, imagettftext

I am making a little app in php which is putting text to image. I got it wotking with imagettftext. I was also able to put it to a imagettfbbox with specific width using this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php#89505. My only problem is that I want the text to be aligned to the right side of the box like on the image[image]

Comment: Need to see your code example. Placement of the TFF Text Box will be based on X, Y values. Please edit and add your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, but I don't need to align whole box to the right on X axis but only the text. You can image it like the text is in html

```
<p style="width:300px;text-align:right">This is the text to be wrapped and aligned to the right</p>
```

---

```
function wrap($fontSize, $angle, $fontFace, $string, $width){

    $ret = "";
    $arr = explode(' ', $string);
    foreach ( $arr as $word ){
        $teststring = $ret.' '.$word;
        $testbox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, $angle, $fontFace, $teststring);
        if ( $testbox[2] > $width ){
            $ret.=($ret==""?"":"\n").$word;
        } else {
            $ret.=($ret==""?"":' ').$word;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

function textToImage(){
    $pluginDir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($pluginDir . 'resources/img/image.png');
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 38, 64, 142);
    $font_path = $pluginDir . 'resources/font/DroidSans.ttf';
    $line = "This is the text to be wrapped and aligned to the right";

    imagettftext($image, 35, 0, 300, 600, $color, $font_path, wrap(18, 0, $font_path, $line, 300));

    imagepng($image, $pluginDir."resources/img/result.png");
    imagedestroy($image);
}
```

Comment: Any help guys? I am getting quite desperate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stil/gd-text](https://github.com/stil/gd-text) class. It does right-alignment and text wrap for  you.

```
<?php
use GDText\Box;
use GDText\Color;

$pluginDir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
$image = imagecreatefrompng($pluginDir . 'resources/img/image.png');

$textbox = new Box($image);
$textbox->setFontSize(35);
$textbox->setFontFace($pluginDir . 'resources/font/DroidSans.ttf');
$textbox->setFontColor(new Color(38, 64, 142));
$textbox->setBox(
    300, // distance from left edge
    600, // distance from top edge
    500, // textbox width
    500  // textbox height
);

// now we have to align the text horizontally and vertically inside the textbox
$textbox->setTextAlign('top', 'right');
// it can wrap multilined text
$textbox->draw("This is the text to be wrapped and aligned to the right");

imagepng($image, $pluginDir."resources/img/result.png");
imagedestroy($image);
```

Demonstration:

[image: demo]